# Pandas read csv where one header is missing

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to read a csv file with Pandas but the first column contains a first name and a last name seperated by a comma. This causes Pandas to think that there are 5 columns instead of 4 so the last column now has no header making it unable to be selected.

The file looks like this:

```
CustomerName,ClientID,EmailDate,EmailAddress
FNAME1,LNAME1,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME1@HOTMAIL.COM
FNAME2,LNAME2,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME2@GMAIL.COM
FNAME3,LNAME3,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME3@AOL.COM
FNAME4,LNAME4,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME40@GMAIL.COM
FNAME5,LNAME5,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME5@AOL.COM
```

What my code looks like now:

```
def convert_ftp_data():
    file = os.getcwd() + "/data.csv"
    data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False)

data["first_name"] = data["CustomerName"].str.split().str[0].str.title()
data["email"] = data["EmailAddress"]

clean_data = data.drop(data[["CustomerName", "ClientID", "EmailDate", "EmailAddress"]], 1)

print(clean_data)
```

Using my code I get the following output:

```
first_name  email
0   FNAME1  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000
1   FNAME1  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000
2   FNAME1  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000
3   FNAME1  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000
4   FNAME1  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000
```

I only need to select the FNAME and EmailAddress field. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: `.iloc` perhaps?

Comment: `df.loc[:, ['first_name','EmailAddress']]` or more precisely using slicing!

Comment: The data with the comma should be enclosed by double quotes `"FNAME1,LNAME1"`

Comment: @DavidLemon Unfortunately I can't control how the data is being sent over

Comment: @user5173426 Can you maybe elaborate a bit on this? trying to understand how to solve this so I won't run into this again

Comment: @Stefan adding the explanation in my answer in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just skip the header and set it correctly after import

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=False, header=None, skiprows=1)

data.columns = 'CustomerFirstName,CustomerName,ClientID,EmailDate,EmailAddress'.split(',')
```

Comment: This gives the following error:
     ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 5 
     elements

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Read the headers separately

With [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), you can utilize `nrows`, `skiprows` and `names` parameters:

```
from io import StringIO

x = """CustomerName,ClientID,EmailDate,EmailAddress
FNAME1,LNAME1,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME1@HOTMAIL.COM
FNAME2,LNAME2,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME2@GMAIL.COM
FNAME3,LNAME3,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME3@AOL.COM
FNAME4,LNAME4,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME40@GMAIL.COM
FNAME5,LNAME5,100,2019-01-13 00:00:00.000,FNAME5@AOL.COM"""

headers = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), nrows=0).columns
headers = np.hstack((['FirstName', 'LastName'], headers[1:]))

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), header=None, skiprows=[0], names=headers)

print(df)

#   FirstName LastName  ClientID                EmailDate        EmailAddress
# 0    FNAME1   LNAME1       100  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000  FNAME1@HOTMAIL.COM
# 1    FNAME2   LNAME2       100  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000    FNAME2@GMAIL.COM
# 2    FNAME3   LNAME3       100  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000      FNAME3@AOL.COM
# 3    FNAME4   LNAME4       100  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000   FNAME40@GMAIL.COM
# 4    FNAME5   LNAME5       100  2019-01-13 00:00:00.000      FNAME5@AOL.COM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['EmailAddress']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'first_name', 'EmailAddress': 'email'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
    first_name  email
0   FNAME1      FNAME1@HOTMAIL.COM
1   FNAME2      FNAME2@GMAIL.COM
2   FNAME3      FNAME3@AOL.COM
3   FNAME4      FNAME40@GMAIL.COM
4   FNAME5      FNAME5@AOL.COM
```